# Add a new row dynamically with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a table with rows. In this table some of rows has a span with class "add". When I click "add" I want to make a new row dynamically. The code works, but when a new row generate it goes at the end of my table. How can I change my code to add a new row only under the row that clicked, not at the end of the table?

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="prices-table" border="1">
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Title<span class="add"><font color="red">add+</font></span></td>
      <td>price</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Title </td>
      <td>price</td>
    </tr>

</table>      
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".add").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('#prices-table')
        .append('<tr><td>newrow</td><td>newrow</td><td>newrow</td></tr>');
});
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at [insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) instead of [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `closest` to the `tr` and then just replace `append` with `after`.

```js
$(".add").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').after('<tr><td>newrow</td><td>newrow</td><td>newrow</td></tr>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="prices-table" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Title<span class="add"><font color="red">add+</font></span></td>
    <td>price</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>price</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change `closest("#prices-table")` to `closest('tr')` and `append()` to `after()`.

This will find `<tr>` element, which is parent of the clicked element, and add the content after it.

See jQuery docs for [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/).

### Demo

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".add").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').after('<tr><td>newrow</td><td>newrow</td><td>newrow</td></tr>');
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="prices-table" border="1">
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Title<span class="add"><font color="red">add+</font></span></td>
      <td>price</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Title </td>
      <td>price</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `after` instead of `append` so you set it `after` the `parent` element of the `span` like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".add").click(function () {
        $(this).parent('tr').after('<tr><td>newrow</td><td>newrow</td><td>newrow</td></tr>');
    });
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the content of your click function to this:

```
$('<tr><td>newrow</td><td>newrow</td><td>newrow</td></tr>')
  .insertAfter($(this).closest("tr"));
```

This way it will insert the row after the closest `tr` element.